# Open D drive using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am editing a powershell script (2.0 I believe) that has the following code to open the cd drive:

```
$sh = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$sh.Namespace(17).Items() | 
Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "CD Drive" } | 
foreach { $_.InvokeVerb("Eject") }
```

The problem is that this script now runs on a computer with multiple optical drives so they all open - I only want the D drive to open. I thought changing the script to the following would work:

```
$sh = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$sh.Namespace(17).Items() | 
Where-Object { $_.DriveID -eq "D:" } | 
foreach { $_.InvokeVerb("Eject") }
```

but it did not (none of the drives opened). How can I only open the D drive?

Comment: I don't see a property called 'DriveId'?  The 'Path' property maybe what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that the result of $sh.Namespace(17).Items() - at least for me - doesn't include a property called DriveID.  It does include "Path" though.  Try the below.

```
$sh = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$sh.Namespace(17).Items() | ? {$_.Path -eq "D:\"} | % { $_.InvokeVerb("Eject") }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering on the `Path` property.

```
$sh = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$sh.Namespace(17).Items() | Where-Object { $_.Path -eq "D:\" } | ForEach-Object { $_.InvokeVerb("Eject") }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a 'DriveID' property, so the Where-Object is filtering all objects (i.e. nothing is passed to the ForEach).  Try using the 'Path' property instead?

```
$sh = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$sh.Namespace(17).Items() | 
Where-Object { $_.Path -eq "D:\" } | 
foreach { $_.InvokeVerb("Eject") }
```